# Shell script [ USe Grep to lookup a files and extract the specific pattern lines]

Tags: file, grep

I am using the following simple shell script to read transaction file against the contents of a master file , and just output  the matching lines from the transaction file.

Transaction file contains:

```
this is a sample line - first
this is a sample line - second
this is a sample line - nth line
```

Master File contains:

```
first
```

Output:

```
this is a sample line - first
```

```
for tranfile in transactionfile.txt
do
  grep -f  MasterFile.txt $tranfile >> out.txt
done
```

PS: When i execute this line outside of the above shel script it works like a charm ; Just that it wont return within this shell script.

What am i missing???

Answer (score 0):

Without the script output text, knowing what shell, i'm just guessing, but i suspect you either fail to find grep in the $PATH ( or using a different version of grep) or fail to find one of the files or you are executing a shell in the command line and another different shell in the script.

Try adding [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) in the script with the correct shell and try to put the grep path (usually /bin/grep or /usr/bin/grep) and also add the full path to the files you are requiring.

To help debug, i suggest you to add a `set -x` to the top of the script, so the shell will output what is doing and you can notice what is missing. This `set -x` may be replaced with a `-x` option in the shebang (example `#!/bin/bash -x` )

`set -x` also work in the command line, use `set +x` to disable it

Answer (score 0):

I would have done this using `awk`

```
awk 'NR==FNR {a=$0;next} $0~a' master transaction
```

- `FNR==NR {a=$0;next}` stores the data from `master` file in variable `a`
- `$0~a` test every line of `transaction` if it contains variable `a`, if so do the default action print the line.

If master file contains more than one word. Test the last field against all words like this:

```
awk 'FNR==NR {a[$0];next} $NF in a' master transaction
```

If word can be anywhere on the line:

```
awk 'FNR==NR {a[$0];next} {for (i in a) if ($0~i) print}' master transaction
```

Comment: I tried the last "awk" statement but it wont write anything to the o/p file.. This is how i tried..   
***************************************************************************************************
for paramfile in $BASEDIR/*.prm
do
  ##grep -f  parameterMaster.txt $paramfile >> out.txt
  awk 'FNR==NR {a[$0];next} {for (i in a) if ($0~i) print}' $BASEDIR/$masterfile $paramfile >> out.txt
  ##
done
***************************************************************************************************

Comment: @veekay Post real data and what you like the output to be.  You do not need to mix `grep` in to this,  `awk` can do it all.

Comment: The grep statement is just commented out from my earlier code.. ..   Master File contains:
First=one
Transaction File
this is a sample line - First
this is a sample line - second
this is a sample line - nth line
Pls note that the "First" keyword can be anywhere in the Line/record
Output
this is a sample line - first
Note-1:  IF i add more Lines in the master File, i should get matching lines , as output, from the Transaction FIle.